# Display field value with value from other tables

Tags: sql, firebird

I have two columns in a table `trades` that refer to an `auto_id` column in another table `customers`.

I want to display the customers' name `customers.customer_name` that corresponds to each `auto_id` in that table, for both columns.

In table trades, the `customer1_id` and `customer2_id` are both foreign keys referring to the same primary key in table `customers`, namely `auto_id`.

Example:

table `customers`:

```
|  auto_id  | customer_name |
|    150    |    jake       |
|    159    |    homer      |
```

table `trades`:

```
| customer1_id | customer2_id |  status  |
|    150       |      159     |  traded  |
|    150       |      160     |   null   |
|    152       |      240     |  traded  |
```

Result expected (in a select or view):

```
| customer1_id | customer2_id |  status  |
|   jake       |     homer    |  traded  |
```

What I'm really trying to achieve: display all trades where jake has traded with a `customer2_id`, and display the customer2's real name in the result (not the `auto_id` if possible, but at the very least its real name).

I only managed to display one `customerX_id` column with a join (not replacing the id, but adding it to the right in the final output), but I can't find a way to have both.

```
select p.customer1_id, p.customer2_id, b.auto_id, b.customer_name
from trades as p
inner join customers as b on b.auto_id = p.customer1_id;
```

Which gives

```
| customer1_id | customer2_id |  status  | auto_id | customer_name |
|   150        |     159      |  traded  |   150   |   jake        |
```

I just need homer to be displayed somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is getting the name of the second customer, then all you need to do is add a second join:

```
select p.customer1_id, p.customer2_id, c1.auto_id, c1.customer_name, c2.auto_id, c2.customer_name
from trades as p
inner join customers as c1 on c1.auto_id = p.customer1_id
inner join customers as c2 on c2.auto_id = p.customer2_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and the formatting)!
I kept having issues doing this because I originally wanted to create a View, but I got the following error doing so: `Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Invalid command
column AUTO_ID appears more than once in ALTER VIEW`
But on its own, this works just fine, thanks.

Comment: @Hernn0 In a view, a column name may only occurs once, so you'll need to alias them if eg `c1.auto_id as c1_auto_id` (although including them is entirely unnecessary as you can have the same value from `p.customer1_id`.